# How do I know how many calories I take daily?

Tags: calories

I want to know around how much calories am I taking everyday. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Read the labels and weigh your food. Do the math.

Answer (score 1):

One extremely simple way for a single person is to record the total calories on all the food packages you purchase when you get home from the store. Over a few weeks, the packages you buy and finish will average out.

The more accurate way is to use [MyFitnessPal](http://myfitnesspal.com/), where you can scan barcodes, pick from a database (eg, you can enter fast food calories just by typing in "Wendy's cheeseburger"), or enter your own recipes and portions. MyFitnessPal also calculates fat and protein calories and makes graphs, which is instructive. It's usually quite surprising to see how things work out.